# How to combine data from two different sources

Tags: sql, sql-server

Apologies for my "stupid" question, but I not familiar with SQL at all.

I have the following two queries and I would like to return only the difference between these two:

```
SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
FROM database1 
WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19' 
ORDER BY [TIME]

SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
FROM database1 
WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18' 
ORDER BY [TIME]
```

I am trying something like that:

```
SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperatureDiff, speedDiff
```

I think I should use `INNER JOIN` but these two queries might not have the same number of rows. The target in the end is to keep all the rows, and if there isn't a row in one query, to use 0 instead in the substraction.

A sample of the table:

[image]

Comment: Tag the DBMS (i.e. `MySQL`, `SQL Server`, etc..) that you are using.

Comment: Use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `ISNULL(col, 0)`

Comment: You should give an example of the inputs and the outputs.  Do you only want to do the subtraction if the `[TIME]` is ***exactly*** the same in both dates?  It seems to me that it's unlikely that two rows will exist with exactly the same `[TIME]`, but  possible, I guess...  By giving us a concrete example of input data and the results that you want from that input, we can help you much more reliably.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Thenassis , Please don't forget to add the SQL type tag when you make the question initially. You added sql-server tag  after asking the initial question.

Answer (score 2):

Although the `OUTER JOIN` and `ISNULL()` or `COALESCE()` answers work, there is an option that is a little more sophisticated and doesn't require a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT
  [TIME],
  SUM(CASE WHEN genDate = '2018-09-19' THEN -consumption ELSE consumption END)   AS ConsumptionDiff,
  SUM(CASE WHEN genDate = '2018-09-19' THEN -temperature ELSE temperature END)   AS TemperatureDiff,
  SUM(CASE WHEN genDate = '2018-09-19' THEN -speed       ELSE speed       END)   AS SpeedDiff
FROM
  database1
WHERE
     (Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19')
  OR (Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18')
GROUP BY
  [Time]
```

Another option that some may think tidier...

```
SELECT
  [TIME],
  SUM(relative_data.consumption)   AS ConsumptionDiff,
  SUM(relative_data.temperature)   AS TemperatureDiff,
  SUM(relative_data.speed      )   AS SpeedDiff
FROM
  database1
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT  consumption,  temperature,  speed WHERE genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT -consumption, -temperature, -speed WHERE genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18'
)
  relative_data
WHERE
  Rev = '1'
GROUP BY
  [Time]
```

Comment: Working example : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c4b80cf983de5787c3ba86c8e1d8a68f

Comment: Nice solution; although you could take the `Rev = '1'` in a separate condition, so you don't have to list it twice: `WHERE Rev = '1' AND ((genDate = '2018-09-20' and runDate = '2018-09-19') OR (genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18'))` Although you could argue that's less readable too, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

One method would be `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.time, t2.time) as time,
       ( COALESCE(t1.Consumption, 0) - COALESCE(t2.Consumption, 0) ) as consumption_diff,
       ( COALESCE(t1.temperature, 0) - COALESCE(t2.temperature, 0) ) as temperature_diff,
       ( COALESCE(t1.speed, 0) - COALESCE(t2.speed, 0) ) as consumption_speed
FROM (SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
      FROM database1 
      WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19' 
     ) t1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
      FROM database1 
      WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18' 
     ) t2
     ON t1.time = t2.time;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    select COALESCE(a.[time],b.[time]),
    case when a.Consumption is null then -b.Consumption when b.Consumption is null then a.Consumption else  (a.Consumption - b.Consumption) end as consumptionDiff, 
    case when a.temperature is null then -b.temperature when b.temperature is null then a.temperature else  (a.temperature - b.temperature) end as temperatureDiff, 
    case when a.speed is null then -b.speed when b.speed is null then a.speed else  (a.speed - b.speed) end as speedDiff
    from
    (
    SELECT [TIME] as time,Consumption, temperature, speed
    FROM database1 
    WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19' 
    )  a full outer join
    (
    SELECT [TIME] as time,Consumption, temperature, speed
    FROM database1 
    WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18' 
    )  b
    ON a.time = b.time
```

Comment: The CASE expression is incorrect.  if `a` IS NULL then the result should be `-b`.

Comment: Thanks, I did changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using `FULL OUTER JOIN` and `ISNULL`, Here I am assuming not more than one row per TIME int both tables.

```
SELECT 

ISNULL(FST.[TIME],SND.[TIME]) [TIME],
ISNULL(FST.CONSUMPTION,0)-ISNULL(SND.COMSUMPTION,0) CONSUMPTIONDIFF,
ISNULL(FST.TEMPERATURE,0)-ISNULL(SND.TEMPERATURE,0) TEMPDIFF,
ISNULL(FST.SPEED,0)-ISNULL(SND.SPEED,0) SPEEDDIFF

FROM
(
SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
FROM database1 
WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19' 
) AS FST
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
FROM database1 
WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18' 
) AS SND 
ON SND.[TIME] = FST.[TIME]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going the route of coalescing (or using `ISNULL`), using a couple of CTEs might make your query a bit clearer:

```
;WITH 
    initialFilter AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM database1 WHERE Rev = '1'
    )
    ,t1 AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM initialFilter
        WHERE genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19'
    )
    ,t2 AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM initialFilter
        WHERE genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18'
    )
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.[TIME], t2.[TIME]) AS [TIME],
    COALESCE(t1.Consumption, 0) - COALESCE(t2.Consumption, 0) AS ConsumptionDiff,
    COALESCE(t1.temperature, 0) - COALESCE(t2.temperature, 0) AS temperatureDiff,
    COALESCE(t1.speed, 0) - COALESCE(t2.speed, 0) AS speedDiff
FROM t1 FULL OUTER JOIN t2 ON
    t2.[TIME] = t1.[TIME]
ORDER BY COALESCE(t1.[TIME], t2.[TIME])
```

Answer (score -1):

Use except operator

```
 SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
 FROM database1 
 WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-20' AND runDate = '2018-09-19' 
 ORDER BY [TIME]
 EXCEPT
 SELECT [TIME],Consumption, temperature, speed
 FROM database1 
 WHERE Rev = '1' AND genDate = '2018-09-19' AND runDate = '2018-09-18' 
 ORDER BY [TIME]
```

Comment: From the OP : `The target in the end is to keep all the rows, and if there isn't a row in one query, to use 0 instead in the substraction.`  This answer doesn't do any subtraction...